# Keep bibliography entry on one page

Tags: page-breaking, natbib

I'm using BibTeX and `natbib`. I have a number of entries in the reference section that start at the bottom of a page and continue on the next e.g. at the bottom of a page I have

> Some Author Name, Title of the Article Begins
>
> [NEW PAGE]
>
> Title continues from previous page, Journal Name, Year, Pages

I need the whole entry to appear on the same page. Is there anyway to make this happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After loading `natbib`, use the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package and its `\apptocmd` macro to add `\interlinepenalty 10000\relax` (which forbids page breaks inside paragraphs) to the definition of `\thebibliography`.

EDIT: Or even easier, redefine `natbib`s `\bibfont` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

% Variant A
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\interlinepenalty 10000\relax}{}{}

% Variant B
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\interlinepenalty 10000\relax}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {\lipsum*[1]},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{A01}

\vspace{30\baselineskip}% Try 29\baselineskip instead!

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, used the first one and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about such a problem if the document is a paper to be submitted, since there's a high chance that the pagination will be different.

If it's a document just for you, don't worry about these problems until the document is in its final form as regards to the text.

The particular problem may be cured by putting `\pagebreak` before the broken citation, in the produced `.bbl` file. Or by following lockstep's directions.

Comment: So this has to be manually inserted after running `bibtex`, right?

Comment: @Werner I misread the question, it seems.