# Bibliography entry spreads over two pages

Tags: biblatex

Sometimes the bibliography entry in the footnote spreads over two pages in my document. I only found a question regarding natbib ([Keep bibliography entry on one page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29983/keep-bibliography-entry-on-one-page)).

Just using `\mbox` doesn't work as the citation then disappear.

How can I keep the citation in the footnote always on one page?

[image: first page]
[image: second page]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
 @Electronic{studiengruppe,
  organization  = {Eidgenössisches Departement für Verteidigung, Bevölkerungsschutz und Sport},
  year    = {2016},
  title   = {Bericht der Studiengruppe Dienstpflichtsystem},
  url     = {https://www.newsd.admin.ch/newsd/message/attachments/44794.pdf},
  date    = {2016-03-15},
  urldate = {2018-12-20},
keywords     = {federal},
}

@Electronic{babs,
  organization = {Bundesamt für Bevölkerungsschutz},
  title  = {Der Wehrpflichtersatz für Schutzdienstpflichtige},
  url    = {https://www.babs.admin.ch/de/zs/pflicht/wpe.html},
keywords     = {federal},
urldate= {2018-10-15},
}

@Electronic{ESTV,
  organization  = {Vereinigung der schweizerischen Steuerbehörden},
  title   = {Die Wehrfplichtersatzabgabe},
  url     = {https://www.estv.admin.ch/dam/estv/de/dokumente/allgemein/Dokumentation/Publikationen/dossier_steuerinformationen/d/d-WPE\_2016.pdf.download.pdf/d-WPE\_2016.pdf},
  date    = {2017-01-01},
  urldate = {2018-10-16},
keywords     = {federal},
}

@Electronic{ungebunden,
  title   = {Fragen und Antworten},
  url     = {https://www.estv.admin.ch/estv/de/home/direkte-bundessteuer/wehrpflichtersatzabgabe/dienstleistungen/fragen-und-antworten.html},
  organization  = {Eidgenössische Steuerverwaltung},
  date    = {2016-10-25},
  urldate = {2018-10-16},
keywords     = {federal},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, 
%twoside
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, headsep=0.75cm, headheight=1cm, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=0.5cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %-- part,chapters,sections, subsections
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %------------ Zeilenabstand 1.5

%--Schrift und Eingabe--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%--weitere Pakete--------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Sprache

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-verbose-ibid,  dashed=false, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}

\section{dfg}
\autocite{studiengruppe}\newpage

\subsection{asdf}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergre

\begin{enumerate}
    \item slkdafj aslkdjf 
    \item asdfasdfasdf 
    \item asdfasdfasdf
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{enumerate}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergre aslkdfj aslkdfjasiofj aklsdjf asoidfj aklsdjf ioasdjif klasdjfadsklfj asdoifj asdkl \autocite{studiengruppe}


\subsection{asdf}
\vspace{1.5cm}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea taksagasdfjk sdfkasdjf lksadfjsdlkfj \footcite{babs}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergre aslkdfj aslk \autocite[S. 6]{ESTV}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos etl\footcite{ungebunden} 


\newpage

sgasdffgasdg
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, without seeing any code how should we be able to help you? to be able to guess we should know the used document class, used packages, used options and show us a screenshot of the issue ... Give as much informations as you can ...

Comment: To produce a MWE: Take your real document, make a copy and remove step by step remove everything that is not necessary to reproduce the problem. Then replace all remaining text with some dummy text and you should have a MWE that you can show us.

Comment: you should easily be able to make a small example based on a copy of your real document, you just need the paragraph with the footnote and add some dummy text or vspace so the paragraph starts in the same place.

Comment: that said, it's possible that you are looking for `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Thanks for your handy tips.- I  finally  managed to create a functioning MWE.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000` solves the problem with spreading the footnote over two pages. However, this creates a ugly space between the text and the footnote.

Comment: @Mico I hope the question is now clearer with the MWE and some more text in the question....

Comment: yes well avoiding the space is why it split the footnote (which normally it tries not to do) so what do you want it to do....

Comment: Characters with special meaning need (and should) not be escaped in the `url` field. In `ESTV` there are some `\_`s that should be only `_` copy and paste the link to see that it does not work as posted. `url     = {https://www.estv.admin.ch/dam/estv/de/dokumente/allgemein/Dokumentation/Publikationen/dossier_steuerinformationen/d/d-WPE_2016.pdf.download.pdf/d-WPE_2016.pdf},` would be correct, but the shorter `url = {https://www.estv.admin.ch/dam/estv/de/dokumente/allgemein/Dokumentation/Publikationen/dossier_steuerinformationen/d/d-WPE_2016.pdf}` also seems to work.

Comment: Note further that it is almost never necessary to give a page prefix like "S.", "p." or "pp." in the postnote argument. `biblatex` can usually figure out automatically whether it is needed: `\autocite[6]{ESTV}` works just as well as `\autocite[S. 6]{ESTV}`. If you are writing a document and follow Swiss German orthography, you might want to use `nswissgerman` instead of `ngerman` (I'm sure the differences are minute, if at all present [there is a difference between `naustrian` and `ngerman` in the month name for January], but it is good practice to use the correct markup anyway.)

Comment: If there are many andvlonger footnotes in a document the chances increase that at one point LaTeX tries to break a footnote over two pages to get a more pleasant page break. `verbose` citations in footnotes are particularly susceptible to this. It is possible to tell LaTeX not to break footnotes, but of course then the space around the page break might look off or sub-par. (After all, there is a reason why LaTeX wants to split the footnote over two pages, it doesn't do that to annoy the document author. It does that to obtain a more pleasant overall result.) ...

Comment: ... In the end you are left with the choice between splitting footnotes over two pages or getting bigger spaces around the page break. If you don't want to live with either, your only chance is to reformulate your text to obtain a different flow and different positions for the footnotes. This might not always be possible, but has in general the greatest chance of getting visually pleasing results. Such reformulation works should be left till the finalisation stages and should be performed from the beginning to end, since changes can have knock-on effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to get the big space added by command `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000` the only thing you can do is rephrasing your text. In your case for example by adding some text like:

```
 This is additional text to avoid the splitting of the footnote or the % <=====================
big space added with `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000`.
This is additional text to avoid the splitting of the footnote or the 
big space added with `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000`. % <===================================
```

So with the complete code (MWE)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Electronic{studiengruppe,
  organization  = {Eidgenössisches Departement für Verteidigung, Bevölkerungsschutz und Sport},
  year    = {2016},
  title   = {Bericht der Studiengruppe Dienstpflichtsystem},
  url     = {https://www.newsd.admin.ch/newsd/message/attachments/44794.pdf},
  date    = {2016-03-15},
  urldate = {2018-12-20},
keywords     = {federal},
}

@Electronic{babs,
  organization = {Bundesamt für Bevölkerungsschutz},
  title  = {Der Wehrpflichtersatz für Schutzdienstpflichtige},
  url    = {https://www.babs.admin.ch/de/zs/pflicht/wpe.html},
keywords     = {federal},
urldate= {2018-10-15},
}

@Electronic{ESTV,
  organization  = {Vereinigung der schweizerischen Steuerbehörden},
  title   = {Die Wehrfplichtersatzabgabe},
  url     = {https://www.estv.admin.ch/dam/estv/de/dokumente/allgemein/Dokumentation/Publikationen/dossier_steuerinformationen/d/d-WPE\_2016.pdf.download.pdf/d-WPE\_2016.pdf},
  date    = {2017-01-01},
  urldate = {2018-10-16},
keywords     = {federal},
}

@Electronic{ungebunden,
  title   = {Fragen und Antworten},
  url     = {https://www.estv.admin.ch/estv/de/home/direkte-bundessteuer/wehrpflichtersatzabgabe/dienstleistungen/fragen-und-antworten.html},
  organization  = {Eidgenössische Steuerverwaltung},
  date    = {2016-10-25},
  urldate = {2018-10-16},
keywords     = {federal},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[%
  12pt,
  a4paper, 
% twoside
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
  left=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, 
  headsep=0.75cm, headheight=1cm, 
  marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=0.5cm, 
  footskip=1cm
]{geometry}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %-- part,chapters,sections, subsections
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %------------ Zeilenabstand 1.5

%--Schrift und Eingabe--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%--weitere Pakete--------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Sprache

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber, 
  style=ext-verbose-ibid,  
  dashed=false, 
  autocite=footnote
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{underscore}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\urlstyle{same}
%\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000


\begin{document}

\section{dfg}
\autocite{studiengruppe}\newpage

\subsection{asdf}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet 
clita kasd gubergre

\begin{enumerate}
  \item slkdafj aslkdjf 
  \item asdfasdfasdf 
  \item asdfasdfasdf
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed 
    diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna 
    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{enumerate}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet 
clita kasd gubergre aslkdfj aslkdfjasiofj aklsdjf asoidfj aklsdjf 
ioasdjif klasdjfadsklfj asdoifj asdkl \autocite{studiengruppe}


\subsection{asdf}
\vspace{1.5cm}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet 
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam 
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea 
rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea taksagasdfjk sdfkasdjf 
lksadfjsdlkfj \footcite{babs}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet 
clita kasd gubergre aslkdfj aslk \autocite[S. 6]{ESTV}Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
This is additional text to avoid the splitting of the footnote or the % <=====================
big space added with `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000`.
This is additional text to avoid the splitting of the footnote or the 
big space added with `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000`. % <===================================
At vero eos etl\footcite{ungebunden} 

%\newpage

sgasdffgasdg
\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pages:

[image]

with footnote 5 on the bottom of corresponding page 3 ...